# multiprocessing.queue module is missing until a Queue is instanced

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

I was working with `Queues` and everything seemed to go fine. However, I found a situation that makes an unexpected `AttributeError` exception to arise.

Let's create the simplest code to create a `Queue`. Don't worry about it's usage, it all happens in the same side, we don't have to worry about the other side that will communicate with it.

```py
import multiprocessing

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
print(type(q))
```

This code will produce as output:

```py
<class 'multiprocessing.queues.Queue'>
```

But what happens if I try to identify if the object is an instance of this class?

```py
isinstance(q, multiprocessing.queues.Queue)
```

Obviously it returns `True`.

Finally, my question arose due to that, if I don't create a `Queue` instance before that checking, the module `multiprocessing.queues` where `Queue` is defined, is not loaded! (Warning, maybe loaded is not the appropriate word here since we are talking about modules. I'm not an expert on it) Let's check it:

```py
import multiprocessing

a = dict()
isinstance(a, multiprocessing.queues.Queue)
```

Where surprisingly we get the failure:

```py
 1 isinstance(a, multiprocessing.queues.Queue)

AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'queues'
```

**Why is this happening? Is this the intended behaviour or is this kind of a bug?**

For me, this represents a problem because in case I want to check if an object is a `Queue` and it's not, if no other queue has been instanced my check could end in an undesired `AttributeError`.

Finally, I would like to add a quick picture with some checks that I did reproducing this, plus adding some checks for the `queues` module inside the `multiprocessing.__all__`.

These checks have been performed in Python 3.9.1. It is worth noting that, when `multiprocessing.queues` was already recognized and therefore the checks didn't throw the `AttributeError`, `queues` was present in `multiprocessing.__dict__`. In the other cases, it is not.

This may seem natural to the expert eye, since `__dict__` is (AFAIK) a list of attributes, but I wanted to point it out since as I said I'm not an expert and I don't know the actual implications of it.

[image]

PS. I've tagged the question as `Python 3.8` since it has been tested in both `3.8` and `3.9` with same results, and in case there are differences I would like the answer for `3.8`. Those differences are likely to appear due to multiprocessing library changes as the docs reflects in several footnotes at the end of the functions.

PS.2. I've been referring to `multiprocessing.queues` as a module due to the output of `multiprocessing.__dict__`. Again I'm not an expert on the matter:

```py
'queues': <module 'multiprocessing.queues' from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\multiprocessing\\queues.py'>
```

Comment: If you want to use ``multiprocessing.queues``, you must ``import multiprocessing.queues``. Relying on something else to do a submodule import for you is always a bad idea, not just for this specific submodule.

Comment: Could you please elaborate that? Clarifying the differences between a regular module import and how it behaves with its submodules seems to be the key to understanding what's happening -not importing a submodule-. Would be a perfect answer. In any case, thanks for pointing that out, since changing the import solves the behaviour exposed in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. If you want to access a submodule, you should import it:

```py
import multiprocessing.queues

a = dict()
isinstance(a, multiprocessing.queues.Queue)
```

Importing submodules adds them as attributes to their parent module – note how `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` is a nested attribute lookup of `Queue` on `queue` after `queue` on `multiprocessing`. An explicit import ensures the submodule will be loaded before accessing it.

> ## The import system: [5.4.2. Submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules)
>
> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs, the `import` or `import-from` statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule.

This means one can get away skipping an explicit export when another action imports the submodule as a side effect. As with all side effects, one has to actually perform the triggering action in order to rely on the side effect.

Since imports are idempotent (repeating them has no ill effect), one should import any module one expects to access instead of relying on side effects of other code.