# How to write nested __init__.py files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I am struggling with nested `__init__.py` in a Python package I am writting. The Package has the following architecture:

```
module/
├── __init__.py
├── submodule1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── source.py
└── submodule2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── source.py
    └── subsubmodule2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── source.py
```

My intent is to be able to access functions defined in `submodule2/source.py` through `module.submodule2.function` and in `subsubmodules2/source.py` through `module.submodule2.subsubmodule2.function`.

The first thing I tried was to define `__init__.py` in `submodule2` this way:

```
from .subsubmodule2 import *
```

But doing so, I get the functions defined in `subsubmodules2/source.py` through `module.submodule2.function` (and `module.function`).

If I do:

```
from . import subsubmodule2
```

I get these functions through `module.subsubmodule2.function`.

I also tried to define `__all__` keyword in `__init__`, with no more success. If I understand well [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), I guess I could leave empty `__init__.py` files and it could work, but from my understanding that is not the best practice either.

What would be the best way to access these functions as intended in my module?

Comment: Maybe you can check PYTHONPATH environment variable, this is the directory where python will find module. By default, this is where you run your code.

Comment: Please clarify what you want. The way you describe it, ``__init__.py`` does not define anything – therefore, there is no "functions defined in ``submodule2``", only "functions defined in ``submodule2.source`` and ``submodule2.subsubmodule2.source``". Are you asking how to pull the objects defined inside ``.source`` into the parent module?

Comment: Thank you for pointing the ambiguity. I clarified in the text, sorry if it was unclear but I obviously meant "functions defined in `submodules2/source.py` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `module` `__init__.py` file write the module which you want to import as

```
from . import submodule1
from . import submodule2
__all__ = ['submodule1', 'submodule2']
```

Now, in submodule1 `__init__.py` file write

```
from . import source
from . import subsubmodule
# if you want to import functions from source then import them or in source.py
# define __all__ and add function which you want to expose
__all__ = ['source', 'subsubmodule']
```

now in subsubmodule `__init__` file define function or class which you want to expose

```
from . source import *
__all__ =  ['source']
# if you want to use * as import, i suggest you to use __all__ in source.py and mention all exposed function there
```

Comment: If I do that, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` error on `submodule1` when importing my module. Am I missing something else?

Comment: just try to change the import statement like `from . import submodule1` or `import submodule1` or `import .submodule1` like these  statements, i only this will cause issue

Comment: `from . import <module>` was the right statement to write at all level, thanks!

Comment: I had a weird situation when I named my main file say `A.py` and had a folder `A`. It got fixed after I renamed it say `B` folder. I guess I had to write `.A.A` but `.A` is already same with `A.A`? idk. wanted to put that here, may help somebody. It can be unnoticeable.

Comment: @FLAW use folder name if it is B then use .B.A

Comment: No there was a problem on `A.A`. let me clear this up: `top/A.py`, `top/A/test.py` when I tried to `from .A.test import tester` in `A.py`, it couldn't get. after I renamed it `top/B/test.py it worked. Didn't dive deep on that error tho.

Answer (score 2):

The `__init__.py` file represents its respective package. For example, `module/submodule2/__init__.py` represents `module. submodule2` .

In order to pull objects defined in submodules into their package namespace, import them:

```py
# module/submodule2/__init__.py
from .source import *
```

Since `__init__.py` is a regular Python module, one can also forgo a separate `.source` module and define objects directly inside `__init__.py`:

```py
# module/submodule2/__init__.py

def function():
    ...
```

---

Note that sub*packages* themselves are already available as their respective name. One does not have to – and in fact should not – import them in the parent module. They will be imported if code *using* the package imports them.

Comment: If I don't import the `submodule` in `submodule`, I don't see it in my namespace.

Comment: Whatever code *uses* the ``submodule`` should import it. That's the point of not importing them in ``__init__.py`` – so that they are only imported as needed. Compare [multiprocessing.queue module is missing until a Queue is instanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142690/multiprocessing-queue-module-is-missing-until-a-queue-is-instanced)

Comment: OK, after testing it I get it. But what buggers me with this is that I tend to use `__init__.py` to expose my API explicitely, and I must also say that I find it much less user friendly in an interactive environment (it is not possible to "discover" the content of the given module).